# MSSQL: difference between servers regarding date conversion

Tags: sql-server, date, date-conversion

I have this script:

```
SELECT UserID, 
       CONVERT(SmallDateTime, cast([1]  + '/' + [2] + '/' + [3] as varchar)) as ReleaseDate, 
       ChannelID
FROM
(
SELECT RU.UserID, U.FieldID,  RU.ChannelID, U.AnswerText
FROM dbo.Users U WITH (NOLOCK) INNER JOIN dbo.ResourceUsers RU WITH (NOLOCK)
      ON U.UserID = RU.UserID
WHERE  (FieldID = 1 -- release day
          OR FieldID = 2 -- release month
          OR FieldID = 3) 
) AS P
PIVOT 
(
      MAX(AnswerText) FOR FieldID in ([1], [2], [3])
) AS pvt
```

The same script runs perfectly on a server. On other server, I got this error:

> Msg 295, Level 16, State 3, Line 3 Conversion failed when converting
>   character string to smalldatetime data type.

Why? What's the difference?
The tables have the same structure on both servers.

Comment: What does the data in 1, 2, and 3 looks like? You should always use yyyy-mm-dd for string representation of a date, since this format will always be interpeted the same in sql server regarless of local, language and date format settings.

Comment: always use a dateformat that is universal, yyyyMMdd is universal and will work in any database

Comment: look at this info http://www.karaszi.com/SQLServer/info_datetime.asp#DtFormatsInput

Comment: Thank you for your answers. @ZoharPeled , [FieldID] [int] NOT NULL

Comment: What version of sql server are you working with?

Comment: MSSQL 2008. Meanwhile, we found the issue. Somebody inserted wrong data format for AnswerText field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In sql server 2012+ you can use [**`datefromparts`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datefromparts-transact-sql)

```
SELECT UserID, 
       convert(smalldatetime,datefromparts([3],[2],[1])) as ReleaseDate, 
       ChannelID
FROM ....
```

Prior to sql server 2012 that you can create a string in 'yyyyMMdd' format

```
SELECT UserID, 
       convert(smalldatetime,
          convert(char(4),[3])
        + right('0'+convert(varchar(3),[2]),2)
        + right('0'+convert(varchar(3),[1]),2)
        ) as ReleaseDate, 
       ChannelID
FROM ....
```